# Counting same data from several column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014.

I have five columns for responses different question, however the different users can possible response the same for different questions.

Getting individual column counts I can do.But how can I get a total of same responses/values from the 5 columns.

```
Column A    Column B   Column C    Column D    Column E
x           x          y           z           aa
y           z          0           0           0
0           x          x           0           x
aa          bb         0           x           aa
```

etc

Comment: Can you share the result you're trying to get for this sample? It would make the question easier to understand.

Comment: @Mureinik  The total response for x: the total response for y:  etc

Comment: @PM77-1 schema--how does this help on count query? each of these columns are nvarchar(10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `union all` operator to get all the values as a single column, and then apply a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   val, COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT a AS val FROM mytable
          UNION ALL
          SELECT b AS val FROM mytable
          UNION ALL
          SELECT c AS val FROM mytable
          UNION ALL
          SELECT d AS val FROM mytable
          UNION ALL
          SELECT e AS val FROM mytable) t
GROUP BY val
```

Comment: @AaronM Here `t` is for [table alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: thanks my mind is not connect the simplest things today